# ComponentLookupError raised on z3c.form based form updateWidgets()

Tags: plone, plone-4.x, z3c.form

I'm having this issue while running tests only after I removed the `<includeDependencies package="." />` directive from my `configure.zcml` file:

```py
Error in test test_get_load_action (sc.embedder.tests.test_content.MultimediaTestCase)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hvelarde/collective/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/hvelarde/collective/sc.embedder/src/sc/embedder/tests/test_content.py", line 135, in test_get_load_action
    edit_form.update()
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/plone.dexterity-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/plone/dexterity/browser/edit.py", line 52, in update
    super(DefaultEditForm, self).update()
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/plone.z3cform-0.7.8-py2.7.egg/plone/z3cform/fieldsets/extensible.py", line 59, in update
    super(ExtensibleForm, self).update()
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/plone.z3cform-0.7.8-py2.7.egg/plone/z3cform/patch.py", line 30, in GroupForm_update
    _original_GroupForm_update(self)
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/z3c.form-2.5.1-py2.7.egg/z3c/form/group.py", line 125, in update
    self.updateWidgets()
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/z3c.form-2.5.1-py2.7.egg/z3c/form/form.py", line 129, in updateWidgets
    (self, self.request, self.getContent()), interfaces.IWidgets)
  File "/home/hvelarde/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/_api.py", line 109, in getMultiAdapter
    raise ComponentLookupError(objects, interface, name)
ComponentLookupError: ((<Products.Five.metaclass.EditForm object at 0x7f5262a3f490>, <HTTPRequest, URL=http://nohost>, <Embedder at /plone/test-folder/multimedia>), <InterfaceClass z3c.form.interfaces.IWidgets>, u'')
```

Same versions where working before; current `configure.zcml` now includes the following:

```xml
<include package="Products.CMFCore" file="permissions.zcml" />
<include package="plone.app.dexterity" />
<include package="plone.app.dexterity" file="meta.zcml" />
<include package="five.grok" />
```

[According to the documentation](http://docs.plone.org/manage/troubleshooting/exceptions.html#z3c-form-based-form-updatewidgets-raises-componentlookuperror) this is a known issue due to a bad migration, but this can't the case.

I'm testing under Plone 4.2.6. Same code works and tests pass under Plone 4.3 as [you can see in the CI builds](https://travis-ci.org/simplesconsultoria/sc.embedder/builds/126185126).

Comment: are the versions of plone.z3cform or z3c.form the same? try to downgrade it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was missing a package on the configure.zcml declaration; now it looks like this:

```xml
<include package="Products.CMFCore" file="permissions.zcml" />
<include package="plone.app.dexterity" />
<include package="plone.app.dexterity" file="meta.zcml" />
<include package="collective.dexteritytextindexer" />
```

and now is working: https://travis-ci.org/simplesconsultoria/sc.embedder/builds/126432050